# Наложение двух объектов друг на друга CSS Grid

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, css-grid

Как на **одной** сетке CSS Grid наложить два объекта так, чтобы один оказался снизу, а другой сверху?

Comment: а почему именно через grid это нужно, в этом есть какое-то преимущество?

Comment: Потому что интересно как это реализовывается через грид.

Answer (score 4):

Надо просто явно задать нахождения ячеек.

К примеру, через `grid-row` и `grid-column`:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 100px; /* размер "неявных" строк, для демонстрации */
  grid-auto-columns: 100px; /* размер "неявных" столбцов, для демонстрации */
}

.item-1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.item-2 {
  background-color: lime;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item-1"></div>
  <div class="item-2"></div>
</div>
```

Для управления наложением используйте `z-index`.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 100px; /* размер "неявных" строк, для демонстрации */
  grid-auto-columns: 100px; /* размер "неявных" столбцов, для демонстрации */
}

.item-1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  z-index: 1; /* чтобы этот был элемент был сверху */
}

.item-2 {
  background-color: lime;
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item-1"></div>
  <div class="item-2"></div>
</div>
```

Также можете сделать через `grid-area`:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: [item-1-start] 100px [item-2-start] 100px [item-1-end] 100px [item-2-end];
  grid-template-rows: [item-1-start] 100px [item-2-start] 100px [item-1-end] 100px [item-2-end];
}

.item-1 {
  background-color: yellow;
  grid-area: item-1;
}

.item-2 {
  background-color: lime;
  grid-area: item-2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item-1"></div>
  <div class="item-2"></div>
</div>
```